# How to open multiple terminals for a single SSH session in MobaXTerm?

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, tmux, mobaxterm

I have the following issue:

I would like to open multiple terminals for the same SSH user session on a remote host via MobaXTerm. Not different sessions, the same user login session (kind of like tmux).

Does somebody know of a solution for this, preferrably without the steep learning curve of tmux?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not use `screen`? Really easy and standard on most Linux distros.

Comment: I would prefer a more graphical approach to window management than `screen` offers, although in general it is a solution.